# Failing to set multiple attributes using .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I set the `.attr()` of my `iframe` by using the variable `attrs` made below ?

```
iosocket.on('content', function (object) {
    var attrs = '';
    for (var key in object) {
        attrs = attrs.concat(",'" + key + "':'" + object[key] + "'");
    }
    attrs = '{' + attrs.substring(1) + '}';
    console.log(attrs);
    var i = $('<iframe></iframe').attr(attrs);
    $('#in').append(i);
});
```

the console.log say it right but it doesn't work, my iframe never get the attrs and no error is dropped.

```
{'width':'853','height':'480','src':'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/qNaknTgIbIg?rel=0','frameborder':'0','allowfullscreen':''}
```

I've also try with `.attr(eval(attrs))`, same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.attr()` function when used as a setter accepts an Object among other alternatives. But, `attrs` is a String and in that case It will react as a getter not as a setter.

I suspect that you need to pass the information as you are receiving it.

```
iosocket.on('content', function(attrs) {
  $('<iframe></iframe>').attr(attrs).appendTo('#in');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer is so simple. I was struggling for nothing.